# Strip specific span tag from HTML content Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, strip

I have the following HTML string , and I need to strip out only specific span tags(those with a pre attribute), but retain the span contents

```
"<P>it <SPAN class='pre="it' ?>is is</SPAN> a movie</P>"
```

I need the following output,

```
"<P>it is is a movie</P>"
```

Comment: do you have a string or a dom element?

Comment: @ArunPJohny its a string.

Comment: No, really what kind of string is this `<SPAN class='pre="it' ?>is is</SPAN>`

Comment: It looks like a messed up string!

Comment: first fix 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ' from string. Because 'pre="it' not valid syntax for java script.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first you should try tu use valid HTML. Then you can use this code :

```
$("<p>it <span class='pre'>is is</span> a movie</p>")
    .find('span') //Used 'span' here since you'll probably change the class name
    .contents()
    .unwrap()
    .parent();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T6cSe/

---

From the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) :

> The .unwrap() method removes the *element's parent.* This is effectively the inverse of the .wrap() method. The matched elements (and their siblings, if any) replace their parents within the DOM structure.

You need to target the content of the span to unwrap the span itself.

Comment: This will remove all spans. OP requires removal of only specific span tags.

Comment: You need to add the class to your span selector.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta True, but that's why I added a comment in the code since his current class name is... special.

Comment: Excellent, I think I'm turning comment-blind. ;) +1

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var html = '<p>it <span class="pre">is is</span> a movie</p>';
var $element = $(html);
$element.find('.pre').contents().unwrap();
```

By suggestion of @Sunny-r-gupta, if you want to get the modified string back...

```
var modifiedHtml = $element.wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
```

Comment: True. Missed the call to `.contents()`. Sorry

Comment: +1 Smart, but now how do we get back the string in string format.

Comment: This way: `$element.html();` and you'll get the modified html. Or, if you want, you can insert the object directly into the DOM with `$element.appendTo()`

Comment: There is a fundamental problem with your code, it being, when you actually try out `$element.html` on your code, it results in `"it is is a movie"`. Not, `<p>it is is a movie</p>`

Comment: Oh, yes, you should have to wrap it before: `$element.wrap('<div></div>').parent().html()`.

Comment: Yep, so just update your answer to reflect the working code, so that the guy who upvoted looks smart. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [unwrap method](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
$('.pre').unwrap();
```

---

Your html string should be this:

```
"<P>it <SPAN class='pre'>is is</SPAN> a movie</P>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code based upon your input type and output

Here anything inside the `p` tag would be saved in  `var html` .
The button is there to give you an insight on how it works.

Refer to the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekverma3189/dwq9s/

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var str = $('<p>it <span class="pre">is is</span> a movie</p>').text();
// str would be "it is is a movie".
var newStr = '<p>' + str + '</p>';
// newStr would be "<p>it is is a movie</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using regex after fix yor string:

your string shouldn't like `"<P>it <SPAN class='pre="it' ?>is is</SPAN> a movie</P>"` because in this string your creating a java script error "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`" so it string should be like as below example:

```
"<P>it <SPAN class='pre=" + "it' ?>is is</SPAN> a movie</P>"
```

or

```
"<P>it <SPAN class='' pre='it' ?>is is</SPAN> a movie</P>"
```

or

```
"<P>it <SPAN class='' pre='it' ?>is is</SPAN> a movie</P>"
```

or

```
"<P>it <SPAN class='pre=it' ?>is is</SPAN> a movie</P>"
```

then use regex pattern to get your desire string like this:

**`JavaScript Code:`**

```
var s= "<P>it <SPAN class='pre=it' ?>is is</SPAN> a movie</P>";
var desireString = s.replace(/<span[^>]+\?\>/i, '').replace(/<\/span>/i, '');
console.log(desireString);
```

**`Output:`**

```
<P>it is is a movie</P>
```

Comment: `JavaScript/Javascript/Java-Script` is acceptable, but please no `Java Script`... :(